# How iterate the values of an API through map in react?

Tags: api, reactjs, superagent

I want to render multiple objects (days) from a weather API

```
const  myApi = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=London,gb&APPID=MY_UNIQUE_ID&cnt=5'
```

I am setting the original state for these values in my APP class:

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      locationName: 'your local area',
      displayUnits: 'F',
      locTemp: '',
      humidity: '',
      weatherSummary: '',
      weatherSummaryDescription: '',
      dayID: '',
      dateFor: '',
      everyDay: []
    };
  }
```

I then set those values with a new state most of which is grabbed from the API:

```
componentWillMount() {
      superagent.get(myApi).then((response) => {
          console.log('CITY NAME IS' + response.body.city.name)
          console.log('RESPONSE BODY IS' + response.body)
        this.setState({
          locationName: response.body.city.name,
          locTemp: response.body.list[0].main.temp,
          humidity: response.body.list[0].main.humidity,
          weatherSummary: response.body.list[0].weather[0].main,
          weatherSummaryDescription: response.body.list[0].weather[0].description,
          dayID: response.body.list[0].dt,
          dateFor: response.body.list[0].dt_txt,
          everyDay: response.body

        })


      });

  }
```

I create a function output for my render function

```
export default class MyForecast extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     displayUnits: props.displayUnits
  };
}



  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Weather for&nbsp;{this.props.locationName}</h1>
        <h3> on {this.props.dateFor}</h3>
        <h2>
            {this.props.weatherSummaryDescription} &nbsp;
            <Temp temp={this.props.locTemp} displayUnits={this.props.displayUnits} clickHandler={this.toggleDisplayUnits.bind(this)}/>
        </h2>
        <WeatherIcon weather={this.props.weatherSummary} />
        <p>The ID for this day is <strong>{this.props.dayID}</strong></p>
      </div>);
  }


  toggleDisplayUnits() {
    this.state.displayUnits === 'F' ? this.setState({
      displayUnits: 'C'
    }) : this.setState({
      displayUnits: 'F'
    });
  }

}
```

Then back in APP I drill through the `everyDay` object in order to generate 5 MyForecast instances with 5 different objects

```
render() {

     return (
       <div>
         {this.state.everyDay.map((data, i) =>
           <MyForecast
             key={i}
             locationName={data.locationName}
             dateFor={data.dateFor}
             weatherSummaryDescription={data.weatherSummaryDescription}
             weatherSummary={data.weatherSummary}
             locTemp={data.locTemp}
             dayID={this.state.dayID}/>
         )}
       </div>
     );
  }
```

This results in 2 errors:

`Uncaught TypeError: this.state.everyDay.map is not a function`

And

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '_currentElement' of null`

Because it has no value for everyDay (body.response) as it is the wrong format (not an array)

Any ideas of how to do this in the correct way?

JSON FORMAT:

```
"city": {
    "id": 2643743,
    "name": "London",
    "coord": {
      "lon": -0.12574,
      "lat": 51.50853
    },
    "country": "GB",
    "population": 0,
    "sys": {
      "population": 0
    }
  },
  "cod": "200",
  "message": 0.1174,
  "cnt": 5,
  "list": [
    {
      "dt": 1485097200,
      "main": {
        "temp": 279.16,
        "temp_min": 278.192,
        "temp_max": 279.16,
        "pressure": 1033.03,
        "sea_level": 1040.8,
        "grnd_level": 1033.03,
        "humidity": 75,
        "temp_kf": 0.97
      },
      "weather": [
        {
          "id": 800,
          "main": "Clear",
          "description": "clear sky",
          "icon": "01d"
        }
...
```

Comment: what is the content of response.body ?

Comment: A JSON object myApi (see above)

Comment: I cant see the response because I don't have the API key

Comment: but, it looks like you want to iterate over response.body.list[X] - as long as you are happy to always access weather[0]

Comment: Also, is there any reason you are setting the state in App?  It looks like it would be fine to store the api response in a variable, and pass it to the props.

Comment: Hey Frazer, I put the API format above. Most of the items are from list[] but city is actually coming from the top of the API. No need to set the state, I just wanted to make sure that everyDay is set as an array.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work:

```
componentWillMount() {
  superagent.get(myApi).then((response) => {
    this.everyDAY = response.body;
  }
}
```

and then in render:

```
 return (
   <div>
     {this.everyDay.list.map((data, i) =>
       <MyForecast
         key={i}
         locationName={this.everyDay.city.name}
         dateFor={data.dt_txt}
         weatherSummaryDescription={data.weather[0].description}
         weatherSummary={data.weather[0].main}
         locTemp={data.main.temp}
         dayID={data.dayID}/>
     )}
   </div>
 );
```

Comment: This doesn't work because map cannot iterate over a JSON object

Comment: oh, you need to add:  `JSON.parse(this.everyDay);`  I'll update my answer

Comment: Thanks but I am getting
```
App.jsx?41d6:28 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> ```

Comment: Either way I don't think it will work because there are multiple arrays inside body.response, not just one. It's an object

Comment: wait, did you try my suggestion before the JSON.parse?

Comment: you just need to go through the results in list[x], correct?

Comment: No, as I said (see JSON above) City is not part of list.

Comment: that is why I referenced it with this.everyDay.city.name - not from the list

Comment: It cannot find it: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` I also tried to define everyDay: body.response.list

Comment: did you change componentWillMount to what I suggested?  if so, what do you get when you console.log(this.everyDay); console.log(this.everyDay.list)

Comment: The same JSON error above + `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`. It still goes back to the fact that map cannot read an object I think